# MySQL SSDictCursor fetchone() takes too much time

Tags: python, mysql, database, python-3.x, mysql-python

I'm processing a large amount of data, I was optimizing my processing loop, but it still takes too much time. So I noticed that every 1000-2000 row from my dataset is fetching with fetchone() for 1-5 seconds! While all the others take 10-30 nano(!)seconds

```
db = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost", user="****", passwd="****", db="****", charset='utf8',
                                 cursorclass=MySQLdb.cursors.SSDictCursor)
    c = db.cursor()
    c.execute(sql)

    while True:
     event = c.fetchone()
     if not event:
       return
     print(event)
```

I was printing the longest fetchone() function calls:

```
(row index : time in sec)
    1898 : 5.86757670 
    3783 : 6.63812080 
    5667 : 5.00934410 
    7559 : 5.21368210 
    9425 : 5.49990800 
    11312 : 4.47716010
```

But on smaller dataset the spikes are also smaller but they happen more often:

```
(row index : time in sec)
    561 : 0.00169070
    714 : 1.43662880 
    1416 : 2.07252320
    2106 : 1.77626870
    2811 : 1.78253030
```

P.S. I guess it might be something with range optimization because I have a big 'id in (*ID's LIST*)' expression inside. But i have problems with NO_RANGE_OPTIMIZATION hints.

Comment: You have a `print` in your loop, try taking that out (the `print(event)` not the one recording the longest events)

Comment: @roganjosh i'm not counting the time of the loop. only the time of fetchone(). And it's just a simplified scheme of the program.

Comment: Hmm ok, I was wondering if it was some kind of buffering issue on stdout